# Restricting a process from writing to it's own memory

Tags: c, windows, memory, windows-10, reverse-engineering

On Windows 10, is there a way I can prevent a process from writing to a small section of memory it owns, without faulting it for trying anyway, and also allowing it to read freely?

I want to inject some of my own much better data into this process's memory, but it's very confused and continuously overwrites my hard work very rapidly, resulting in jitters. (the data relates to a camera's transformation matrix in a video game, the camera jitters as I wrestle the process.)

I am attacking it in C, if it is helpful.  I am unsure if this is a very hard problem, or easy peasy, but any direction is thanked!

Comment: This is not supported, and whatever you are trying to do, you are going about it the wrong way.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Might be easier to ask about the actual problem lol

Comment: @JoseFernandoLopezFernandez - I'm writing an .exe to hijack a game's camera, as a mod (the game has no exposed api for this)

Comment: @MissCutiecutler Oh, wow, that's actually pretty cool. I get the jitter now, yea. Could you maybe NOP the calls it's making to update the view instead? Something in the style of writing data to `/dev/null`, so the action fails successfully lol

Comment: @JoseFernandoLopezFernandez - I could try that, I do that in Ida-pro already but, maybe I can make a backup of the exe on my user's machine then edit it.  I'm sure it'll drive every antivirus under the sun crazy, but that was gonna happen no matter what haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Mark the memory region read-only with `VirtualProtect()`
2. Attach a "debugger" that traps the first-chance exception and steps around the writes to the memory.

Or do it the right way and track down the camera updater that you're fighting with and zap it (replace a critical bit with nop so it does nothing interesting, preferably using as little CPU as possible).

Comment: thank you for the direction, I'll try that, and if it doesn't work... I use Ida to do the instruction replacement while REing already, I'll try to figure out the least intrusive way to do that on my mod user's machines too, and I should be golden!

Comment: @MissCutiecutler: By debugger I mean implement a small program using the debugging APIs to do exactly that. I haven't done that but I've done other exotic things with the debugging APIs.

Comment: Note that "step around the write" is nontrivial.  Since x86 instructions are of variable length, the only way to know how many bytes to advance the program counter is to basically disassemble the instruction, so you need to be able to recognize all opcodes, decode effective addresses, etc.  Also some memory write instructions might have other side effects, e.g. `movsb`, `stosb`, which you would have to emulate.

Comment: There is also a separate problem if the target memory region isn't an entire page; there could be writes to other stuff on that page, which you don't want to skip.  I think the only way to handle those is to mark the page read-write temporarily, resume the instruction with the trace flag set, and then have a debug exception handler which sets the page back to read-only after the instruction completes.

Comment: Finally, all this will be very slow - with one or more exceptions on every instruction that touches the page, expect a slowdown of 100x-1000x.  I agree that finding and patching out the code that does the writes is much better.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I took the opinion if OP persists, OP will find out why zap is better.